# How do I use the unstable std::collections::BitVec?

Tags: data-structures, rust, bitvector

I'm trying to use the `std::collections::BitVec`, but this error is generated:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `std::collections::BitVec`
 --> src\main.rs:6:5
  |
6 | use std::collections::BitVec;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `BitVec` in `collections`
```

I'm using `#![feature(collections)]` at the top of the main.rs and my compiler version is `rustc 1.27.0-nightly (ac3c2288f 2018-04-18)`. What am I missing? The error is saying that `BitVec` doesn't exist at `std::collections`, but the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.2.0/std/collections/struct.BitVec.html) say that `BitVec` is an unstable feature.

My Cargo.toml looks like:

```
[package]
name = "conways_game_of_life"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Gabriel Carneiro <gabriel.carneiro97@live.com>"]

# [lib]
# crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies]
wasm-bindgen = "0.2"
rand = "0.4.2"
time = "*"
```

What am I supposed to do to use an unstable feature like `BitVec`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking at old documentation. `BitVec` was unstable in Rust 1.2, but you can see in the [Rust 1.3 documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.3.0/std/collections/struct.BitVec.html) that it was not stabilised, but instead moved into its [own crate](https://crates.io/crates/bit-vec).